# JOLT: How to convert datetimestamp to epoch on dynamic json keys

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

[Edited] I have a use case, where i have to convert the datetimestamp fields to epoch but the fields are not standardized as  in some flowfiles we may not receive the datetime fields, My conversion is working perfectly using the **EvaluateJsonPath** and **JoltTransformation JSON**.

**My Input** :

```json
{    
  "updated_on": "2023-03-14 03:56:22",
  "created_on": "2023-03-14 03:56:22"
}
```

**My Jolt Spec** :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "assign": "${assign:toDate('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'):toNumber()}",
      "updated_on": "${updated_on:toDate('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'):toNumber()}",
      "i_date": "${i_date:toDate('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'):toNumber()}",
      "created_on": "${created_on:toDate('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'):toNumber()}"
    }
  }
]
```

**Desired Output** :

```
{
  "updated_on": "1678766182",
  "created_on": "1678766182"
}
```

[image: EvaluateJsonPath Configuration]

But i am still not understand why i am getting error whenever any one or two of datetimestamp field missing out of four

Comment: Everything is fine, just convert the `"operation": "default"` to `"operation": "modify-overwrite-beta"` for the JoltTransformJSON processor.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan : I have changed the operation, but still i'm getting the error and flowfile which not contains the datetimestamp fields are not being processed. I'm trying to log :
`JoltTransformJSON[id=b2e134d4-a3b6-1f06-97f3-cc44fdc9c5e6] Unable to transform FlowFile[filename=65c94b0e-e1d1-43c8-a945-88b80f98b7a5] due to org.apache.nifi.attribute.expression.language.exception.IllegalAttributeException: Cannot parse attribute value as a date; date format: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss; attribute value: : org.apache.nifi.attribute.expression.language.exception.IllegalAttributeException:`.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan : Thanks for the detailed view, but the problem is that, If any field is missing out of these four from the flowfiles, it give us error and not process the file. 
My expectation is simple, all of the datetimestamp fields (assign,created_on,i_date and updated_on) regardless of whether they are present in the flowfiles, it should be processed and convert to Epoch **I have edited my question for screenshot**

Comment: OK, you can convert the `Path not found behavior` property to `skip`. I've just edited the question as well.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan : Tried this property, but it will works only when there is no attribute present in flowfile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let' reproduce your case;

By adding four processes :

**GetFile** :

- ***Input Directory***  - [defined] ( example : *C:\ApacheNifi\App\JSON* )
  where there's a flowfile.json with *flowfile II* as the content
- ***Keep Source File*** - *true*

**EvaluateJSONPath** :

- ***Destination*** - *flowfile-attribute* //to be individually used within the next(Jolt) transformation

  with added properties :

  ```
     Property    Value
     ----------- -------------
     created_on  $.created_on
     updated_on  $.updated_on
  ```
- ***Path not found behavior*** - *skip* => there will be the key name of the attribute while the value is **""** (eg. ***{"created_on":"1678755382000","updated_on":""}***) if the related attribute ( in this case **updated_on** ) doesn't exist within the *flowfile.json* file.

**JoltTransformJSON** :

- **Specification** :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta", // replacing "default" with this is important in order to 
                                          // be able to override the values of the existing attributes
    "spec": {      
      "updated_on":"${updated_on:toDate('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'):toNumber()}",
      "created_on":"${created_on:toDate('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'):toNumber()}"      
    }
  }
]
```

- **LogAttribute**

[image]

*Run once* each process except for *LogAttribute*

As a result, you can get a result similar to the one you've defined as the ***desired result*** for the **flowfile II** from the **List queue** in the **last Connection**'s context menu.

Comment: Hi @self lab , Can you please voteup also as only votingup increases the score for the tag badges. Thanks in advance.